# Elementary os 6 Odin not updating due to unmet dependency

Tags: updates, nvidia, dependencies

A "Failed to update “Operating System Updates”" message is displayed in a pop up and, if I click "Details", it shows the following:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  linux-modules-nvidia-470-5.11.0-40-generic: Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-470 (<= 470.82.00-1) but 470.86-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 is to be installed
```

If I run `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get upgrade` it shows the same message as above. If there is a fix in the works let me know and, if I can fix it myself, I am willing to do so if its not too complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to solve my issue, i removed the nvidia 470 driver through app center by the following way:
open appcenter->clicking the installed tab->then by selecting nvidia-driver-470-> click uninstall-> reboot system.
then after reboot:
open appcenter->go to installed tab->wait for the updates to show up->update all->open terminal->paste this command (without quotes) "sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall"->when this command is finished rebooted my system.  now my system is running normally, i even got some new update that got installed without any issues.  so it seems like the problem is solved.

matigo gave an answer which i used to solve the installation of the driver through command line.  sadly due to me not having enough reputation, i cant upvote his answer.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to resolve this by re-installing the common libraries for the Nvidia driver.

From a Terminal, run this command to re-install the common libraries:

```
sudo apt --reinstall install libnvidia-common-470
```

Then ensure you have the proper hardware drivers installed:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Comment: also how do i close this thread

Comment: Glad that you could resolve your issue. This site is a Q&A site, so doesn't work like a forum where threads are open or closed. The best option would be to write an answer, explaining what you did with a step-by-step for other people, then mark that as the accepted answer 

Comment: ok, i'll delete my comment and paste it as an answer.  stay safe, have fun and thanks for the directions.

Comment: I had to run `sudo apt --reinstall install nvidia-kernel-common-470`, which installed 233Mb of packages solving my issue!